# Submit a Struts 2 form without changing the page?

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a Struts2 form that is included in a DIV overlay on a page.  When I submit this form I want it to hide/show a hidden text area on the bottom of the form that just lets the user know that the form was submitted.  From there the user could close the overlay and return back to their work.  I'm having a problem accomplishing this.  Upon my Return of a `SUCCESS` or `NONE` the page will redirect to a blank page if I do not provide it with another page in the return.  How can I submit the form and stay within the same page without redirecting at all?

Currently I am submitting the form using JavaScript

```
document.forms['formName'].submit();
```

I am using JavaScript as opposed to the `<s:submit/>` option because there are other parameters that need to be set on the form itself prior to form submission.

Comment: You have to use Struts2-Jquery. javascript is not an easy way. and if yeW are using framwork, then y don't you take advantage from their plugins rather than simple javascript.
and setting parameters is not an issue.

Comment: Show your code here. It ll be helpfull fo solving the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is: [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

In Struts2 you can achieve it out-of-the-box with an `<sx:div>` of the( deprecated since Struts 2.1, but still here and working) [Struts2-Dojo Plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-dojo-plugin).

Basically, you target the div with the dojo topic, and the result of your Action, a JSP file containing an HTML/JSP snippet, will fill the div without reloading the page.

But if you are using the latest versions of Struts2, you can easily achieve this with [Struts2-jQuery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/), and you can find all the working example with the code too in [its Showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action).

This is an example:

```
<s:url id="ajax" value="/ajax1.action"/>
<sj:div href="%{ajax}" indicator="indicator">
       <img id="indicator" src="images/indicator.gif" 
            alt="Loading..."    style="display:none"/>
</sj:div>
```

Pretty easy :)

You can obviously alter the `href` attribute with `javascript` too, if you need to set parameters at runtime... just get id by id and alter `href` attribute.

Comment: What if, for some reason, you had to accomplish this with Struts2 and AJAX only, no plugins.  Is it possible?  JavaScript and jQuery are usable.

Comment: Of course you can, plugins are only built to help you to avoid writing all the stuff from zero, they encapsulate the logic and expose it through Struts2 tags, but the underlying technology doesn't change. What you need is the load() method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7163395/1654265

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ***Ajax call***.
Please look at the example below,

***Struts.xml configuration:***

```
    <action name="**ActionName**" class="**Actionclass**"   method="**Method-calling**">
        <result type="stream">
            <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
            <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
        </result>
        <result name="input">/Error.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

***Action Class***
public class **ActionClass** extends ActionSupport
{
    private InputStream inputStream;

```
public String **Method-calling()** 
{
    //Calling Business Logic
            if(Business logic check condition)
                 {
         inputStream=new StringBufferInputStream("return x");               
                 }
    else
         {
         inputStream=new StringBufferInputStream("return y");
         }
    return SUCCESS;
}

public InputStream getInputStream() 
{
    return inputStream;
}
public String execute() 
{
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

}

***Html file*** *Ajax call exxample*

```
jQuery('***#replace-with-tag-id***').on('***blur(can  be any action)***', function() {
    var varE = jQuery('***#replace-with-tag-id***').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            method:"GET",
            url: "***Actoin-name-struts.xml***.action", //"callAJax.action",
            data: "email="+varEmail,
            success: function(data) 
                                    {
                if(""+data == "return x") 
                                    {
                                    alert("x has been returned");
                } 
                                else 
                                    {
                                    alert("y has been returned");
                }
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('Error=' + textStatus);
                alert("errorThrown"+errorThrown);
                alert("response text = "+XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }

        });
    } 
}).trigger('blur');
```

I hope, i have cleared your doubt.