# How to use ajax to dynamically update results

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I have an area which shows results generated by ASP and SQL. I wish to use ajax to update this area instead of refreshing the page each time.

I have looked at plenty of tutorials, w3c, etc. None have helped.

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: Are you using asp.net ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163278/best-performance-jquery-ajax-div-refresh

Comment: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/98/Ajax-with-Classic-ASP-using-jQuery

Comment: post some codes you've tried so far

Comment: are you having trouble on the browser side, or the server side?
does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163278/best-performance-jquery-ajax-div-refresh

Answer (score 0):

This assumes the ajax call returns the html you want to use when replacing the old one.

```
$.get('/path/to/file', function(data) {
    $('#my_replaced_div').html(data);
});
```